# How does one determine if a named NSColor does not exist in bundle?

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, nscolor

In preparation for all of the upcoming macOS color changes (i.e., Dark Mode), I'm attempting to use colors defined in an xcassets file. I reference the colors through their name like this:

```
NSColor(named: NSColor.Name("App Control Foreground Color"))
```

I would expect, if the specified color name didn't exist in any of the available resources, that this NSColor initializer would return nil, and I would be able to write code like this:

```
NSColor(named: NSColor.Name("App Control Foreground Color")) ?? NSColor.textColor
```

Instead, if the named color does not exist, the initializer creates a non-color with an unspecified color space. This, in turn, can really just makes things get colored as transparent when in use and generates no warnings.

What's a good way to detect if a Named color doesn't actually exist in the bundle and that the NSColor(named:) initializer has given me a "bad" color instead?

Comment: The line `let color = NSColor(named: NSColor.Name("Invalid Color"))` in a Swift playground results in the error "Unable to encode a color which does not have a color space".

Comment: I don't seem to get this warning when running a true macOS app. I will get some console warnings if I try to do certain invalid operations against one of these "non-colors" - like try to get the red/blue/green color components. But, I'd like to know my color is invalid long before that point.

Comment: Looks like a bug. Maybe you can check its `colorNameComponent`?

Comment: I issued a code level support ticket with Apple and they've confirmed it appears to be a bug. Submitted a [bug report](http://www.openradar.me/radar?id=4937462174449664) and will update this question if I get any more info from Apple.